# Как задать предельное количество символов в регулярном выражении?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Стоит такая задача: написать регулярку, которая проверяет телефонный номер на валидность.

Условия:

- В номере может быть символ '+'
- Номер может содержать 0-2 знаков '-', которые не могут идти подряд
- Номер может содержать 1 пару скобок '(' и ')', причем если она
  есть, то она расположена левее знаков '-', в скобках и между '-' должно быть 1+ символов
- А самое главное номер должен быть строго 10 символов.

У меня получилось такое:

```
/^\+?\d*(\(\d+\))?\d*((\-\d+\-)|\-?)?\d*/
```

Никак не могу понять, как задать конкретное количество символов. То есть я не знаю, в каком конкретном месте будет '(' или '-' и будут ли они вообще. А заодно ещё и такой вопрос: Как улучшить (уменьшить) данное выражение?

Как решить задачу без регулярки, я представляю, но хочется разобраться именно в тонкостях регулярных выражений. Беглый поиск по этой теме ничего не дал.

Comment: Символ `+` разве не только в начале номера у кода страны может быть? Но если код страны в номере присутствует, то для России это 11 цифр получается. Приведите пример валидного по вашему запросу номера с символом `+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть очень простая методика, которая позволяет легко описать подобные регулярные выражения.
Суть заключена в следующем - сперва разрешаются все возможные символы, а потом с помощью позиционных проверок эта последовательность проверяется на соответствие правилам, причем одна позиционная проверка - одно правило, что существенно упрощает понимание и изменение таких регулярных выражений.

То есть сначала мы разрешаем все допустимые символы в нужном количестве, в конкретном случае это выглядит так:

```
^\+?(?:[()-]*\d){10}[()-]*$
// 10 цифр, а между ними могут быть скобки и тире в любом количестве и порядке
```

Далее выделим четкие правила, которые можно описать отдельными позиционными проверками:

1. В номере может быть символ `+`
   Не беру в расчет это правило, потому что нужно просто вставить `\+?` в начало всего регулярного выражения, а все остальные проверки вставлять после этой конструкции.
2. Номер может содержать 0-2 знаков '-'

   ```
   (?!(?:.*-){3})
   ```
3. Знаки `--` не могут идти подряд

   ```
   (?!.*--)
   ```
4. Может быть только одна пара скобок `()`

   ```
   (?=[^()]*\([^()]+\)[^()]*$|[^()]*$)
   ```
5. Скобки обязательно левее `-`

   ```
   (?!.*-.*[()])
   ```
6. Между `-` как минимум 1 символ: лишнее правило, так как это равносильно отсутствию `--` (со скобками наличие одного символа реализовано в **4**)

Теперь объединяем все это в одно регулярное выражение:

```
^\+?(?!(?:.*-){3})(?!.*--)(?=[^()]*\([^()]+\)[^()]*$|[^()]*$)(?!.*-.*[()])(?:[()-]*\d){10}[()-]*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/lB8eW1/1

Регулярное выражение собрано исключительно на основе правил, которые описаны в тексте вопроса, если оно будет находить что-то не то, значит правила описаны не в полном объеме.

Comment: @Yukon, Ваш вопрос звучит `Как задать предельное количество символов в регулярном выражении?`, а не как построить регулярное выражение по вашим правилам, но отличное от вашего :Р

Comment: `+-1234567890-` валидный номер.

Comment: @Visman, не ставил себе цель написать регулярное выражение для очередного частного случая под нужды конкретного человека. Хотелось просто описать методику реализации регулярных выражений в которых задана совокупность множества правил.

Comment: вопрос состоял не в этом :Р

Comment: удалить строки меньше 35 символов, как задать регулярное выражение?

Answer (score 4):

Ответ на вопрос: *Как проверить, точно ли 10 цифр в представленном номере?*

```
/(?=(^([^\d]*?\d){10}$))/
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/hN2xK6/1

1. Вы можете совместить это регулярное выражение со свои регулярным выражением так

   ```
   /(?=(^([^\d]*?\d){10}$))^\+?\d*(\(\d+\))?\d*((\-\d+\-)|\-?)?\d*$/
   ```

   Тест https://regex101.com/r/oN3rW4/1 (в вашем выражение пробелы запрещены, в отличии от регулярного выражения @Saidolim Djuraev)
2. Регулярное выражение требует в конце строки наличие цифры, в отличии от вашего выражения.

Comment: Спасибо. Наконец-то разобрался!

Answer (score 0):

думаю вам поможет следуюшее конструкция

```
/(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}/
```

подходит вариантам как

```
123-456-7890
(123) 456-7890
123 456 7890
+91 (123) 456-7890
```

только не знаю по поводу 10 символов. так как много различных ситуаций