# Спец символы в RegExp

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как составить регулярные выражения, которые позволят использовать две специальных символа в".″ и «-» (точку и дефис). Эти символы нельзя использовать в начале или в конце. Нельзя использовать более 1 любого символва.

Минимальное количество символов — 3.
Максимальное 16.

Сейчас выглядит рег. выражение так

> ([0-9A-Za-z]{2,16})|([0-9\u0410-\u044f]{2,16})

И позволяет использовать англ. или рус. алфавит + цифры.

Comment: Напишите примеры строк на которые выражение должно срабатывать и на какие нет. по тексту плохо понятно. И регулярное выражения для какого диалекта. В javascript например возможностей у выражений гораздо меньше. Кстати ваше выражение позволяет в принципе любую длину строки, оно просто захватывает буквы-цифры.

Comment: @Mike на Java к примеру. .Abc21 - нельязя, -Abc332 - нельзя, А.bc332 - можно, А-Bc322 - можно. Abc322-  - нельзя, Abc322. - нельзя

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что поможет. Просто оставлю: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450416/481

Comment: @mass_ попробуйте `^(?![-.]|(?:.*[-.]){2,})(([-.0-9A-Za-z]{2,16})|([-.0-9\u0410-\u044f]{2,16}))(?<![-.])$`  https://regex101.com/r/iW8wH7/1  Но пришлось вводить признаки начала и конца строки (`^$`), что может не подходить конкретно в вашей задаче. Вы не указали в вопросе тестируете ли вы всю строку или используете это для захвата части строки. Если подойдет - скажите, как ответ оформлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение с PCRE - https://regex101.com/r/pW7nJ7/2

#### Само регулярное выражение:

```
/^(?:(?<!^[.-])(?'char'[\w\d.-])(?!.*?(?P=char))(?![.-]$)){3,16}$/gmi
```

#### Описание:

3-16 символов, для каждого из которых 4 требования:

- `(?<!^[.-])` = перед символом не стоит "`начало строки` + `.` или `-`"
- `(?'char'[\w\d.-])` = разрешенный символ (запоминается как `char`)
- `(?!.*?(?P=char))` = после символа не стоит "`любые символы` + `char`"
- `(?![.-]$)` = после символа не стоит "`.` или `-` + `конец строки`"

#### Обрабатываемые ситуации:

- `.abc12` - начитается с запрещенного символа
- `abc12.` - оканчивается запрещенным символом
- `abc12c` - содержит повторные символы
- `ab` - длина 2<3
- `0123456789abcdefg` - длина 17>16
- `abc12` - корректная строка - **совпадение**