# Регулярное выражение: только один пробел в середине выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как написать регулярные выражение не пропускающее пробел в начале и в конце и пропускающее один пробел в середине? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Какие символы допускаются справа и слева от пробела?

Comment: В начале строки и в конце строки не пропускать пробел,пропускать только середине один пробел

Comment: Речь идет об имени? Допускаются только буквы или в нем можно использовать цифры, знаки препинания?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

может быть, что-то такое

```
^[^ ]([^ ]| (?!.+ .+))+[^ ]$
```

[демо](https://regex101.com/r/lF3aF9/2)

Comment: $.validator.addMethod("has_space", function (value, element) {
    return !(/^\s+\s+$/).test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid input.");Этот кусок  код  в начале и в конце не пропускает пробел тепер как добавит код пропускающее один пробел в середине?

Comment: Ваше регулярное выражение не пропустит текст из 1 или 2 литералов :(

Comment: @ReinRaus да, вы правы - минимум 3 .

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение можно разбить на 3 условия:

1. Не должно начинаться с пробела
2. Не должно заканчиваться на пробел
3. Не должно быть двух пробелов в тексте

Сделаем позиционные проверки под каждое из трех условий:

1. `^(?! )`
2. `(?!.* $)`
3. `(?!(?:.* ){2})`

Помимо этих условий разрешим все остальные литералы в строке:

```
^.*$
```

и объединим все в одно регулярное выражение:

```
/^(?! )(?!.* $)(?!(?:.* ){2}).*$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/fK9pA3/1

---

Формально - пустая строка подходит под описанные условия, но скорее всего для практических задач должен быть минимум 1 символ в тексте, значит добавим еще одно правило:

4. Минимум один символ в тексте

Решим его так: `^.+$`

```
/^(?! )(?!.* $)(?!(?:.* ){2}).+$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/fK9pA3/2

Comment: Регулярное выражение составлено на основе методики, описанной здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450416/481 (к сожалению не знаю где найти авторитетного источника для данного метода).

Comment: класс час проверю

Answer (score 1):

Вроде можно в прямую:

```
/^[^ ]+( [^ ]+)?$/
```

1. `^[^ ]+` - в начале строки некоторое кол-во непробельных символов.
 2. `( [^ ]+)?$` - после чего следует возможная группа из пробела и некоторого кол-во непробельных символов.

Comment: че то не получилась

Comment: может не так объяснил

Comment: не допускать пробел в начале строки и в конце строки.И пропускать в середине строки только один пробел

Comment: А что не получилось?
    `> var name = 'John Doe';`
    `undefined`
    `> name.match(/^[^ ]+( [^ ]+)?$/)
    [ 'John Doe',
      ' Doe',
      index: 0,
      input: 'John Doe' ]`

Comment: проблема не решено ((((((((((

Comment: $.validator.addMethod("has_space", function (value, element) {
    return !(/^\s+|\s+$/.test(value));
}, "Please enter a valid input."); это рабощий код не пропускаеть пробол в начале и в конце строки не могу добавить сюда пропускающий один пробел середине строки

Comment: может написать отдельный выражение

Comment: тогда как указать середине строки?

Comment: `return value.match(/^[^ ]+( [^ ]+)?$/) != null;`

Comment: или `return /^[^ ]+( [^ ]+)?$/.test(value);`

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
var name = 'John Doe';
if(name.match(/^\w+ \w+$/i)) console.log('Success');
else console.log('Fail');
```

Comment: а для jquery plugin как написать регулярные выражение

Comment: @cheops я так понимаю, что пробела может и и не быть

Comment: середине пропускать только один пробел