# Регулярное выражение математического выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как проверить при помощи регулярок, правильность ввода математического выражения? Все не как не могу додумать, математическое выражение может включать в себя следующий набор символов =+-*/()[a-z].
То есть это список корректных выражений:

```
x=x+1
(x+1)=sav*10/(2+1)
a+b=c
(r+w)/2
a=3+5/(3*10(-10/4))
+a--3+50
```

А это список некорректных:

```
=2+r
((d+f)
*e=f
g=/3
3=4//5
x=5/
df=
```

Т.е. по идее нужно рекурсивно раскрыть скобки, и проверить последовательность определенных символов.

Comment: Примените метод из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448942/Как-задать-предельное-количество-символов-в-регулярном-выражении . Чётко сформулируйте критерии правильного математического выражения и выразите эти критерии языком регулярных выражений.

Comment: Скобки в общем случае не подсчитываются регекспами, кажется.

Comment: @bipll я находил примеры как через рекурсию скобки проверяли, вроде корректно работало)

Comment: И? Где регекспы, а где рекурсия? Или "при помощи регулярок" читается как "как-нибудь, но чтобы регулярки тоже там были"? :-\

Comment: Данная задача решаема регулярными выражениями, в том числе и баланс скобок может быть соблюден.

Comment: да я в курсе что решаем, у меня проблема с решением

Comment: Так забавно- куча подобных вопросов, а этот получает минус и закрытие как «учебное задание». Подавляющее большинство вопросов в топике регулярных выражений сводится к написанию регулярного выражения за ТС и очень мало по теории. И такие вопросы получают плюсы и кучу положительных ответов. В чем проблема с этим вопросом? Что регулярное выражение будет немного сложнее и кому-то он будет не по зубам? :-)

Comment: @ReinRaus вот тоже не понимаю, видел подобные темы, и все решалось. К слову у меня уже есть 6 отдельных регулярок каждая из которых покрывает особое условие, но мне не хватает знаний в регулярках что бы все 6 слить в одну.

Comment: Если вы собрались объединить 6 выражений в 1, где же они в вопросе? Или хотите, чтобы мы заново трудились над ними? Кстати, рекурсия в регулярных выражениях поддерживается очень немногими библиотеками, а "балансированные конструкты" вообще доступны только в .NET.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew везде где поддерживается рекурсия делается баланс чего-нибудь. Вот только в НЕТ ужасная реализация рекурсии в регулярных выражениях... Но не буду оспаривать- это дело вкуса.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew не понял Вашего комментария... Возможно, пропущены слова или знаки препинания...

Comment: @ReinRaus *Вот только в НЕТ ужасная реализация рекурсии в регулярных выражениях* - рекурсия в регулярных выражениях .NET не поддерживается вообще.

Answer (score 4):

Окей, вопрос решился, оставлю регулярку для потомков:

```
( 
    ( 
        (          (?<=^|\(|\=|\+|\-|\*|\/)   ([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*) (?=$|\)|\=|\+|\-|\*|\/) ) | 
        (          (?<=^|\(|\=|\+|\-|\*|\/)   (\d+)                 (?=$|\)|\+|\-|\*|\/)    ) | 
        (          (?<=[a-zA-Z\d])            (\=)                  (?=[a-zA-Z\d]|\(|\+|\-) ) | 
        (          (?<=^|[a-zA-Z\d]|\=|\(|\)) (\+|\-)               (?=[a-zA-Z\d]|\()       ) | 
        (          (?<=[a-zA-Z\d]|\))         (\*|\/)               (?=[a-zA-Z\d]|\()       ) | 
        (?<level>  (?<=^|\=|\(|\+|\-|\*|\/)   (\()                  (?=[a-zA-Z\d]|\(|\+|\-) ) | 
        (?<-level> (?<=[a-zA-Z\d]|\))         (\))                  (?=$|\)|\+|\-|\*|\/)    )   
    )+ 
    (?(level)(?!)) 
)$
```

Comment: можно рабочий пример на каком-нить онлайн сервисе типа https://regex101.com/ ?